# Company Intranet Using Apache/PHP/PostgreSQL, Want to Switch to Node.js

Tags: php, node.js

Up until now I've been using Apache, PHP, and PostgreSQL to run our company intranet (maybe 50-75 concurrent users, small database). I was looking into package managers and frameworks to help with the organization of this intranet.

I was looking at Laravel for the framework and Composer for the package manager. But then I stumbled upon node.js (heard of it and used it a bit in school but never touched it again) and now I'm thinking that I want to "switch over" from PHP to node.js.

The further I dive into looking at all of this though the more confused I am becoming. Do I still need Apache with node.js? Can node.js completely replace all my PHP logic? Do I still need a framework with node.js?

As mentioned the intranet would have around 50-75 concurrent users, the database has 15 tables, and the intranet has 36 pages. I'm using Bootstrap, Font Awesome, data-tables, hopscotch, and select2.